# Android-unity3d application crash at a random time with fatal singal 11

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

Firstly, here is the information by logcat:

```
01-02 13:11:26.060 3653-3653/? A/libc: @@@ ABORTING: heap corruption detected by dlfree
01-02 13:11:26.060 3653-3653/? A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadbaad (code=1), thread 3653 (com.testunity3d.tester)
01-02 13:11:26.160 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
01-02 13:11:26.160 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'Freescale/sabresd_6dq/sabresd_6dq:4.3/1.1.0-rc4/20131206:user/dev-keys'
01-02 13:11:26.160 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG: Revision: '405525'
01-02 13:11:26.160 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG: pid: 3653, tid: 3653, name: com.testunity3d.tester  >>> com.testunity3d.tester <<<
01-02 13:11:26.160 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr deadbaad
01-02 13:11:26.160 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG: Abort message: '@@@ ABORTING: heap corruption detected by dlfree'
01-02 13:11:26.360 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     r0 00000027  r1 40091c08  r2 00000000  r3 deadbaad
01-02 13:11:26.360 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     r4 00000000  r5 beaf6c04  r6 00000003  r7 40130034
01-02 13:11:26.360 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     r8 00000003  r9 00000004  sl 00000006  fp 63aa50c0
01-02 13:11:26.360 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     ip 00000001  sp beaf6c00  lr 4010612b  pc 40103684  cpsr 600f0030
01-02 13:11:26.360 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     d0  7149f2ca3f000000  d1  3f8000003f000000
01-02 13:11:26.360 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     d2  000000003f000000  d3  33d6bf953f000000
01-02 13:11:26.360 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     d4  3f80000044344000  d5  4409000043020000
01-02 13:11:26.360 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     d6  3f800000449a4000  d7  00000000442b8000
01-02 13:11:26.360 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     d8  0000000000000000  d9  000002f040c00000
01-02 13:11:26.360 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     d10 400921fb54442d18  d11 3fd34413509f79fe
01-02 13:11:26.360 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     d12 3ddb7cdfd9d7bdbb  d13 0000000000000000
01-02 13:11:26.360 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
01-02 13:11:26.360 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     d16 3fb999999999999a  d17 0000000000000000
01-02 13:11:26.360 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     d18 0000000000000000  d19 0000000000000000
01-02 13:11:26.360 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     d20 0000001200000000  d21 0000000b00000000
01-02 13:11:26.360 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     d22 0000000900000008  d23 000000080000000a
01-02 13:11:26.360 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     d24 0000000000000000  d25 0000000000000000
01-02 13:11:26.360 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     d26 3ff0000000000000  d27 0000000000000000
01-02 13:11:26.360 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     d28 0000000400000006  d29 0000000700000006
01-02 13:11:26.360 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     d30 0000000900000008  d31 000000080000000a
01-02 13:11:26.360 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     scr 20000012
01-02 13:11:26.370 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG: backtrace:
01-02 13:11:26.370 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     #00  pc 0001e684  /system/lib/libc.so
01-02 13:11:26.370 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     #01  pc 0001c550  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
01-02 13:11:26.370 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     #02  pc 000121f1  /system/lib/libc.so
01-02 13:11:26.370 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     #03  pc 0000e915  /system/lib/libc.so
01-02 13:11:26.370 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     #04  pc 00010ec1  /system/lib/libc.so (dlfree+1216)
01-02 13:11:26.370 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     #05  pc 0000d9df  /system/lib/libc.so (free+10)
01-02 13:11:26.370 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     #06  pc 00019c15  /system/lib/libhwui.so
01-02 13:11:26.370 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     #07  pc 0002189b  /system/lib/libhwui.so
01-02 13:11:26.370 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     #08  pc 000218b9  /system/lib/libhwui.so
01-02 13:11:26.370 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     #09  pc 00011dc7  /system/lib/libhwui.so
01-02 13:11:26.370 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     #10  pc 0001262d  /system/lib/libhwui.so
01-02 13:11:26.370 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     #11  pc 00012f71  /system/lib/libhwui.so
01-02 13:11:26.370 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     #12  pc 00012fb1  /system/lib/libhwui.so
01-02 13:11:26.370 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     #13  pc 0001262d  /system/lib/libhwui.so
01-02 13:11:26.370 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     #14  pc 00012f53  /system/lib/libhwui.so
01-02 13:11:26.370 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     #15  pc 00012fb1  /system/lib/libhwui.so
01-02 13:11:26.370 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     #16  pc 0001262d  /system/lib/libhwui.so
01-02 13:11:26.370 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     #17  pc 00012f53  /system/lib/libhwui.so
01-02 13:11:26.370 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     #18  pc 00012fb1  /system/lib/libhwui.so
01-02 13:11:26.370 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     #19  pc 0001262d  /system/lib/libhwui.so
01-02 13:11:26.370 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     #20  pc 00012f53  /system/lib/libhwui.so
01-02 13:11:26.370 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     #21  pc 00012fb1  /system/lib/libhwui.so
01-02 13:11:26.370 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     #22  pc 0001262d  /system/lib/libhwui.so
01-02 13:11:26.370 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     #23  pc 00012f53  /system/lib/libhwui.so
01-02 13:11:26.370 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     #24  pc 00012fb1  /system/lib/libhwui.so
01-02 13:11:26.370 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     #25  pc 0001be71  /system/lib/libhwui.so
01-02 13:11:26.370 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     #26  pc 00064af5  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
01-02 13:11:26.370 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     #27  pc 0001dc4c  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
01-02 13:11:26.370 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     #28  pc 0004decf  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+398)
01-02 13:11:26.370 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     #29  pc 00027060  /system/lib/libdvm.so
01-02 13:11:26.370 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     #30  pc 0002b5ec  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
01-02 13:11:26.370 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     #31  pc 000601df  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInvokeMethod(Object*, Method const*, ArrayObject*, ArrayObject*, ClassObject*, bool)+350)
01-02 13:11:26.370 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG: stack:
01-02 13:11:26.370 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:          beaf6bc0  ffffffff  
01-02 13:11:26.370 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:          beaf6bc4  00000000  
01-02 13:11:26.370 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:          beaf6bc8  4012d170  /system/lib/libc.so
01-02 13:11:26.370 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:          beaf6bcc  40091c08  
01-02 13:11:26.370 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:          beaf6bd0  00000015  
01-02 13:11:26.370 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:          beaf6bd4  4010510d  /system/lib/libc.so (__sflush+56)
01-02 13:11:26.370 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:          beaf6bd8  4012d220  /system/lib/libc.so
01-02 13:11:26.370 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:          beaf6bdc  40130498  
01-02 13:11:26.370 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:          beaf6be0  00000000  
01-02 13:11:26.370 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:          beaf6be4  4010612b  /system/lib/libc.so (_fwalk+34)
01-02 13:11:26.370 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:          beaf6be8  401053d5  /system/lib/libc.so (_cleanup)
01-02 13:11:26.370 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:          beaf6bec  beaf6c04  [stack]
01-02 13:11:26.370 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:          beaf6bf0  00000003  
01-02 13:11:26.370 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:          beaf6bf4  40130034  
01-02 13:11:26.380 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:          beaf6bf8  df0027ad  
01-02 13:11:26.380 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:          beaf6bfc  00000000  
01-02 13:11:26.380 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     #00  beaf6c00  40130204  
01-02 13:11:26.380 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:          beaf6c04  fffffbdf  
01-02 13:11:26.380 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:          beaf6c08  7b5b0000  
01-02 13:11:26.380 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:          beaf6c0c  00000035  
01-02 13:11:26.380 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:          beaf6c10  ffffffff  
01-02 13:11:26.380 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:          beaf6c14  00000000  
01-02 13:11:26.380 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:          beaf6c18  00000003  
01-02 13:11:26.380 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:          beaf6c1c  beaf6c44  [stack]
01-02 13:11:26.380 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:          beaf6c20  77c902e8  
01-02 13:11:26.380 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:          beaf6c24  40101554  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_clone)
01-02 13:11:26.380 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     #01  beaf6c28  00000000  
01-02 13:11:26.380 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:          beaf6c2c  400f71f5  /system/lib/libc.so
01-02 13:11:26.380 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     #02  beaf6c30  beaf7054  [stack]
01-02 13:11:26.380 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:          beaf6c34  00000030  
01-02 13:11:26.380 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:          beaf6c38  beaf6c44  [stack]
01-02 13:11:26.380 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:          beaf6c3c  beaf6c74  [stack]
01-02 13:11:26.380 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:          beaf6c40  beaf7043  [stack]
01-02 13:11:26.380 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:          beaf6c44  20404040  
01-02 13:11:26.380 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:          beaf6c48  524f4241  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
01-02 13:11:26.380 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:          beaf6c4c  474e4954  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
01-02 13:11:26.380 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:          beaf6c50  6568203a  /system/framework/telephony-common.odex
01-02 13:11:26.380 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:          beaf6c54  63207061  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-LinearAlloc (deleted)
01-02 13:11:26.380 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:          beaf6c58  7572726f  /dev/graphics/galcore
01-02 13:11:26.380 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:          beaf6c5c  6f697470  /dev/graphics/galcore
01-02 13:11:26.380 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:          beaf6c60  6564206e  /system/lib/libstagefright.so
01-02 13:11:26.380 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:          beaf6c64  74636574  /dev/graphics/galcore
01-02 13:11:26.380 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:          beaf6c68  62206465  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-mark-stack (deleted)
01-02 13:11:26.380 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:          beaf6c6c  6c642079  /dev/graphics/galcore
01-02 13:11:26.380 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:          ........  ........
01-02 13:11:26.390 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG: memory near r1:
01-02 13:11:26.390 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     40091be8 00000004 400946b0 40bab880 40094930  
01-02 13:11:26.390 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     40091bf8 00000003 00000007 00000004 0000100b  
01-02 13:11:26.390 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     40091c08 6d206e49 69616d67 4e4a206e 6e4f5f49  
01-02 13:11:26.390 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     40091c18 64616f4c 0000000a 6c706d61 74615265  
01-02 13:11:26.390 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     40091c28 38223d65 22303030 2020200a 20202020  
01-02 13:11:26.390 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     40091c38 6e696d20 6e616843 736c656e 2231223d  
01-02 13:11:26.390 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     40091c48 78616d20 6e616843 736c656e 2231223d  
01-02 13:11:26.390 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     40091c58 0a3e2f20 2020200a 75413c20 456f6964  
01-02 13:11:26.390 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     40091c68 646f636e 61437265 616e2070 223d656d  
01-02 13:11:26.390 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     40091c78 77726d61 65202262 6c62616e 223d6465  
01-02 13:11:26.390 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     40091c88 65757274 20200a22 20202020 696d2020  
01-02 13:11:26.390 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     40091c98 7469426e 65746152 3636223d 20223030  
01-02 13:11:26.390 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     40091ca8 4278616d 61527469 223d6574 35383332  
01-02 13:11:26.390 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     40091cb8 200a2230 20202020 6d202020 61536e69  
01-02 13:11:26.390 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     40091cc8 656c706d 65746152 3631223d 22303030  
01-02 13:11:26.390 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     40091cd8 78616d20 706d6153 6152656c 223d6574
01-02 13:11:26.390 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG: code around lr:
01-02 13:11:26.390 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     40106108 4a0e4b0d e92d447b 260041f0 4680589c  
01-02 13:11:26.400 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     40106118 686768a5 f9b5e007 2b00300c 4628dd02  
01-02 13:11:26.400 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     40106128 430647c0 3f013554 6824d5f5 d1ef2c00  
01-02 13:11:26.400 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     40106138 e8bd4630 bf0081f0 00026ec8 ffffffc4  
01-02 13:11:26.400 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     40106148 43f0e92d fb01461e 4b16f502 4916460f  
01-02 13:11:26.400 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     40106158 447bb087 aa014614 20019001 95029203  
01-02 13:11:26.400 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     40106168 90049505 681a585b b1124698 f0094630  
01-02 13:11:26.400 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     40106178 4630fd26 f7ffa903 4681fe9c 0000f8d8  
01-02 13:11:26.400 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     40106188 4630b110 fd28f009 0f00f1b9 9c05d005  
01-02 13:11:26.400 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     40106198 1b284639 eb30f017 46204604 e8bdb007  
01-02 13:11:26.400 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     401061a8 bf0083f0 00026e7a ffffff60 46036842  
01-02 13:11:26.400 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     401061b8 60411e51 da012900 bb9ef000 f8126802  
01-02 13:11:26.400 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     401061c8 601a0b01 00004770 4a104b0f b570447b  
01-02 13:11:26.400 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     401061d8 589b4604 461e6819 f009b109 6860fcf0  
01-02 13:11:26.400 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     401061e8 60651e45 da042d00 f0004620 4605fb85  
01-02 13:11:26.400 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     401061f8 6822e003 5b01f812 68336022 4620b113  
01-02 13:11:26.400 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG: memory map around fault addr deadbaad:
01-02 13:11:26.400 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     bead7000-beaf8000 rw- [stack]
01-02 13:11:26.400 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     (no map for address)
01-02 13:11:26.400 2406-2406/? I/DEBUG:     ffff0000-ffff1000 r-x [vectors]
01-02 13:11:26.680 2410-2710/? I/AudioFlinger: BUFFER TIMEOUT: remove(4099) from active list on thread 0x40ee8008
01-02 13:11:26.800 3653-3722/? W/AudioTrack: releaseBuffer() track 0x65ba54a8 name=0x3 disabled, restarting
01-02 13:11:26.800 2686-4697/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.testunity3d.tester/.MainActivity
01-02 13:11:26.800 2686-2708/? I/BootReceiver: Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_05 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
01-02 13:11:26.830 2408-2408/? D/Zygote: Process 3653 terminated by signal (11)
01-02 13:11:26.830 2686-2725/? W/InputDispatcher: channel '41cab868 com.testunity3d.tester/com.testunity3d.tester.MainActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
01-02 13:11:26.830 2686-2725/? E/InputDispatcher: channel '41cab868 com.testunity3d.tester/com.testunity3d.tester.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
```

I use unity3d to display a 3d model and move and transform it periodically, but after a random time, my application crashed and I get informations like below.

I really don't know what caused such situation and how can I debug such problems.

Anyone had met such things?

(I removed some I/DEBUG codes since the editor tells me that the code's length is a bit longer than what I described.)

My Unity3d's version is 5.4.0, and my panel of  Android is in version 4.3.

I tried to read some other familiar questions, but it seems not that helpful to me.

Comment: I think you should post that code you are using. That will help determine what's going on

Comment: Yes, that and the first suggestion you'll get anyways is to try to update Unity and rebuild the program. Also, try to toggle "Optimize Mesh Data" in build settings.